# Max value of a Mat datatype variable

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv, so please help me in solving this basic query. I am trying to find the max. value of a Mat variable. I tried to use the max_element and minMaxLoc, but end up facing errors, as the function keeps saying the datatype matched is wrong. I checked it over and over again, but am not successful. here is my code.
ABS_DST is the MAT variable

```
    double *estimate,*min;
    CvPoint *minLoc,*maxLoc;


    Size s = abs_dst.size();
    int rows = s.height;
    int cols = s.width;
    double imagearray[rows][cols] = abs_dst.data();


    minMaxLoc(imagearray,min,estimate,minLoc,maxLoc);
```

I even tried giving the Mat variable abs_dst directly. But have not succeeded. there's an optional input mask array, which I have ignored as I do not require that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. Thanks for your efforts. The problem is minMaxLoc doesn't take RGB images array, as it is 3 channel. I had to convert the ABS_DST to Gray scale.

Secondly,

it is not

```
    CvPoint *minLoc,maxLoc;
```

it is

```
    Point *minLoc,*maxLoc;
```

I need not convert it to array, as converting to Gray Scale will directly give me a 1D channel, enough for the minMaxLoc. My apologies for my own mistakes and thanks once again for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Do next:

```
Point[] Mat_To_Point = Your_Mat_Variable.toArray();
```

And next you can to sort your array